# Sharepoint List attachments migration to online Environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-list

I have been tasked with migrating a list from an Sharepoint 2013 environment to Sharepoint Online.

Searching through the tools used to migrate such content, i have decided to use the SPMT in order to undergo the migration process.
I am troubled by some posts revealing that list-item attachments do not get migrated.

Is there any solution around this, since i will have to migrate the list-item attachments also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, SharePoint migration tool supports the migration of list attachments to SharePoint Online.

List with attachments in SharePoint server:

[image]

Migrate to SharePoint online using SPMT:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info @Julie_MSFT!
I did a test run myself and it worked like a charm.
I am troubled about the fact that it was written in a developers personal blog that it did not transfer his attachments.